# How to set relative classpath for jasper reports

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jasper-reports

I am creating a jasper report from a swing application.It is working fine when the absolute path is set but not generating one for a relative path. The java code for generating the code is

```
 JasperDesign jd= JRXmlLoader.load("relative path");

    String sql = "";
    JRDesignQuery newQuery= new JRDesignQuery();
    newQuery.setText(sql);
    jd.setQuery(newQuery);
    JasperReport JASP_REP= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    JasperPrint JASP_PRINT= JasperFillManager.fillReport(JASP_REP,null,conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT,false);
```

When ever I am trying with the absolute path errors are occuring.The xml code for the the data source is

```
<defaultValueExpression >
        <![CDATA["reports/report1.jasper"]]>
    </defaultValueExpression>
```

But it is showing the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: reports/report1.jasper (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have got some suggestions from

http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/relative-path-for-subreport-in-jasperreport-309313.html

but none are helping in this scenerio.

Comment: where is your jrxml file situated.

Comment: added example as comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `Jasper` `Swing` application then it's best practice that path must be absolute. Just compile all `.jrxml` files to `.jasper` files and load compiled `.jasper` file always. It is fast.

create folder like `jaspers`, `images`, `styles` out side of application. And create `system/environment` variable like below.

```
JASPERDIR = "c:\\app\\jaspers";
STYLES = "c:\\app\\styles";
IMAGES="c:\\app\images";
```

Now in your swing application Use the `System.getenv()` method, passing the name of the variable to read the path.

In this way **your swing application is flexible enough** every time. You can change `images`, `styles`, `.jasper` files any time without restarting your swing application.

Comment: @Firefly.... thank you for ur response.. can u give some more details on the System.getenv() method(may be a snippet).. Having created the environment variables ,I am not able to access them using the method

Comment: RightClick-MyComputer-properties-AdvanceTab-EnvironmentVariable. Now Click new and put variable name as `JASPERDIR` and variable value  as `"c:\\app\\jaspers";`. Now most important thing restart eclipse. write a simple client class and in main method write below code `System.out.println(System.getenv("JASPERDIR"));`

Comment: Thanks .... it helped to understand the issues with my code... !! i am sure this is gonna work..thumbs up..!!

Comment: Glad to hear this. if you like the answer then accept it and upvote.